# Limit of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^3}{x+y}$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Limit of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^3}{x+y}$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$.
I couldn't do it by polar coordinates, or Epsilon-Delta.
I'm pretty sure it's $0$.

Comment: What happens on the line $y=-x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approaching the origin along either axis yields a limit of $0$.

But if you approach the origin along the curve $y=x^4-x$, we get
$$
f(x,y)
=\frac{x(x^4-x)^3}{x+(x^4-x)}
=\frac{x^4(x^3-1)^3}{x^4}
=(x^3-1)^3
$$
which approaches $-1$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Hence the limit in question doesn't exist.

Comment: Oooh I see! Thank you very much!